# data from php echo inside jquery `if` statement

Tags: php, jquery, if-statement

```
function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    $("#info").html(data);
    if ((data).substr(0, 5)=="Please") {$("#imgOk").fadeIn();} // doesn't work
```

`data` is is php echo from another page. It is successfully placed into div `#info` and it's content is:
`Please, check your Inbox`.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit... like what is the problem

Comment: @TheCOMPLETEPHPNewbie, there is no error. Just `imgOk` is not fadedIn

Comment: What happens if you alert data? What string do you get?

Comment: You did the substring wrong. Please is 6 characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `data` is fine, `substr`'s second parameter is the amount of characters to retrieve, not the ending index. As "Please" is 6 letters, it should be `.substr(0, 6)`.

See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp for more info.